# How can I use Google Cloud Speech-to-Text from Angular App

Tags: angular, azure-cognitive-services, google-cloud-speech

I have a angular application in which I want to integrate a bot with dialogflow NLP. So I want to integrate the Speech recognization ability to the bot. I am trying to use Google cloud speech API or Azure cognitive service Speech to text API. As the documents are provided only for server side for both the APIs. Can anyone suggest the way to integrate any one of that API in angular or any other way to provide the Speech input and output ability to angular application apart from web speech API.

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Google Cloud, but for Azure the reason to do the connection on the server side is to control access to the Azure service. If you do the authentication to Azure client side, that means that the user can use that authentication to do whatever they want on your service and you are stuck with the bill. Not a good situation.

The correct way to implement this is to use your backend as a go between. The user authenticates to your backend and then your backend authenticates to Cognitive services. While it is an extra step that way your users never have direct access to the API endpoint directly. Because of the security issue, this is a common pattern, not just with Cognitive Services.

If you understand that this is a serious risk and still want to use an Angular app, take a look at [Node samples](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/quickstart/javascript/node). While these are still server-side example, it's going to be fairly close to how you would implement in Angular.

Comment: Ok thanks. Do you have idea of integrating the Google assistant in an angular app.

Comment: I haven't yet had the opportunity to work with the Google Assistant, sorry.